# How can I shut down my Python based TCP server correctly?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tcp

I have a Python 3 based socket server, listening on a TCP connection. 
It works perfectly, but now I want to be able to shutdown the whole application "gracefully", even when one ore more clients are still connected to the server.

The following code shall just demonstrate the structure, I removed some functions which are not important for the question:

```
    def createContentHandler(server = None):
        """
        Creates TCP Request Handler with given message handler
        """
        class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
            def handle(self):
                """
                Request handler in a loop receives and handles message and send back response
                """
                id = threading.get_ident()
                sock = self.request
                try:
                    while True:
                        msg = self.receiveMessage()
                        data = msg.decode("utf-8")
                        response = server._msghandler.handle(data)
                        self.sendMessage(response)
                except ConnectionResetError as e:
                    sock.close()
                    print("socket close by client")
                except Exception as e:
                    sock.close()
                    print("socket close by other reason")




        return ThreadedTCPRequestHandler

    #======================== CLASS =====================================       

    class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
        """
        Handle each request in a separate thread.
        """

    #======================== CLASS =====================================       

    class Socket_Server():

        def __init__(self, *, adress, port, msghandler):
            super(Socket_Server, self).__init__()
            self._adress = adress
            self._port = port
            self._msghandler = msghandler


        def run(self):
            print('TCP socket server starting...')
            server_address = (self._adress, self._port)
            tcpHandler = createContentHandler(self) 
            print('TCP socket server is running.')
            with ThreadedTCPServer(server_address, tcpHandler) as server:
                self._server = server
                server.serve_forever(0.5)

        def shutdown(self):
            if self._server is not None:
                self._server.shutdown()
                self._server.server_close()
                print("Server is shut down")
```

In principle the server is started by `server.serve_forever()` and (thanks to some magic behind) a content handler  is started in a separate thread for each connection.

The content handler calls `self.receiveMessage()`, which internally calls `sock.recv(count)` to receive data from the socket. This call is blocking.

When I want to shutdown the application, I call `shutdown()` on the server from the main thread. I get the message `"Server is shut down"`, but the application still hangs on the location where the blocking receive is executed. Only when all clients have been disconnected, the application quits completely because of handling of `ConnectionResetError`.

How can I force the content handler for a connection to shut down on demand? In fact I have to break the blocking call within the loop in the content handler, but how?

Comment: You could change the while true to something like `While !Shutdown` and have `Shutdown` as a boolean which you can change when you request the shutdown

Comment: This would be easy if msg = self.receiveMessage() were not blocking. But it is waiting here for some input from the client. So the loop is not looping in the idle state.

Comment: You could make the socket [nonblocking](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking), i.e. effectivley set a [timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) on your server threads, allowing the loop to continue and act upon an altered state of the while loop's condition as @Jaxi suggested. You'd have to handle the timeout error that recv() will raise if it does not receive anything though.

Comment: I wanted to avoid additional load for polling. This would be a solution, but is it  really the way it should be implemented? If yes, I would do it so, but I have a bad smell...

Comment: You should avoid `While True` whenever possible, but if you're against the idea of this and timing out, you could always just have shutdown send a local socket request which you can handle and shutdown that way.

Comment: Why is one class in a function and one other does not have a base class but calls `super()`?

Comment: @Klaus: The function is a closure returning a class. The other class has a base class, but I removed it for clarity in the posting, because it is not important here.

Comment: Anyway: I did it with 5 seconds timeout now. This doesn't generate much polling overload and works as expected. Thanks.